# Execute a list of methods passed as parameter of a function

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

I would like to achieve such a following function:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(params Func<T[], void>[] funcs)
{
   foreach (var func in funcs)
   {
      func();
   }
}

public void Print1<T>(params T[] objs)
{
   Console.WriteLine("==== I am in 1 ====");
}

public void Print2<T>(params T[] objs)
{
   Console.WriteLine("==== I am in 2 ====");
}

static void Main()
{
   MyMethod(
      Print1(1, 2, 3),
      Print2("1", "2", "3"),
   );
}
```

expecting to execute outputting:

```
==== I am in 1 ====
==== I am in 2 ====
```

What i managed so far is this:

```
public void MyMethod2(params Action<object>[] funcs)
{
   foreach (var func in funcs)
   {
      Execute(func);
    }
 }

 public Action<object> Print1<T>(params T[] objs)
 {
     PrintLog("==== I am in 1 ====");
     return null;
 }

 public Action<object> Print2<T>(params T[] objs)
 {
     PrintLog("==== I am in 2 ====");
     return null;
 }

 public class MyDelegateCommand : ICommand
 {
    public MyDelegateCommand(Action<object> executeAction) => _executeAction = executeAction;
    private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _executeAction?.Invoke(parameter);
 }
```

but the problem is that I get printed twice, like this:

```
==== I am in 1 ====
==== I am in 2 ====
==== I am in 1 ====
==== I am in 2 ====
```

I think the reason in this second approach is because the `object` of the `Actioon<object>` not being passed/returned, but i anyway ask me if it wouldn't be better to manage it with the first approach i am requesting. Any idea how could I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is `Execute`, as invoked in `MyMethod2`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper it's declared in `public class MyDelegateCommand : ICommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```cs
public static void MyMethod(params Action[] funcs)
{
   foreach (var func in funcs)
   {
      func();
   }
}

public static void Print1<T>(params T[] objs)
{
   Console.WriteLine("==== I am in 1 ====");
}

public static void Print2<T>(params T[] objs)
{
   Console.WriteLine("==== I am in 2 ====");
}

static void Main()
{
   MyMethod(
      () => Print1(1, 2, 3),
      () => Print2("1", "2", "3")
   );
}
```

In particular: the `<T>` is not common between the two calls, so it cant be generic on `MyMethod`; fine in `Print1<T>` and `Print2<T>` though, as the respective `<T>` is specified (implied) in the lambda.

Comment: Thanks, but this proposal still prints logs twice like in my second approach...

Comment: @anna I literally ran the code, and no: it didn't; please look very very carefully for any difference between what I posted above, and what you have locally

Comment: i did as welll.... may it be any configuration different by me?

Comment: @anna https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwJSn.png - on config: seems very unlikely